# Diameter of closed curve is perpendicular to velocity?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let $\gamma$ be a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $d:\mathbb{R^2}\times\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be the distance function between two points of $\gamma$. I'm trying to show that if the distance between two points $p_1,p_2$ is maximal, then the line spanned by connecting these points is perpendicular to the $\gamma'$ at $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Attempt:
Let's instead look at the square of $d$ to determine distance. If $d(p_1,p_2)=(\gamma(p_1)-\gamma(p_2))\cdot(\gamma(p_1)-\gamma(p_2))$ is maximal then that means $d'(p_1,p_2)=0$. Therefore:
\begin{align}
D[(\gamma(p_1)-\gamma(p_2))\cdot(\gamma(p_1)-\gamma(p_2))]&=
2D[(\gamma(p_1)-\gamma(p_2))]\cdot(\gamma(p_1)-\gamma(p_2))]\\
&=0\\
\implies
D[(\gamma(p_1)-\gamma(p_2))]\cdot(\gamma(p_1)-\gamma(p_2))]
&=0\\
\implies
D[(\gamma(p_1)]\cdot(\gamma(p_1)-\gamma(p_2))-D[\gamma(p_2))]\cdot(\gamma(p_1)-\gamma(p_2))
&=0\\
\implies
D[(\gamma(p_1)]\cdot(\gamma(p_1)-\gamma(p_2))
&=D[\gamma(p_2))]\cdot(\gamma(p_1)-\gamma(p_2))\\
\end{align}

But from here I don't see how you can conclude that both of these sides must be equal to zero which is what I need to show...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\gamma:\  t\mapsto {\bf x}(t)$
be the given curve, whereby it is assumed that ${\bf x}(\cdot)$ is $C^1$ and
periodic with some period $T>0$, and that ${\bf x}'(t)\ne{\bf 0}$ for all $t$.

We want to find the two most distant points on $\gamma$. To this end we consider the doubly periodic function
$$f(s,t):=|{\bf x}(t)-{\bf x}(s)|^2=\langle{\bf x}(t)-{\bf x}(s),\ {\bf x}(t)-{\bf x}(s)\rangle .\tag{1}$$
At the point(s) $(s_*,t_*)$ where this function is globally maximal we necessarily have
$${\partial f\over\partial s}=0,\quad{\partial f\over\partial t}=0\ .$$
From $(1)$ we deduce
$${\partial f\over\partial t}=2\langle{\bf x'}(t),\ {\bf x}(t)-{\bf x}(s)\rangle\ .\tag{2}$$
When ${\bf d}:={\bf x}(t)-{\bf x}(s)\ne{\bf 0}$ the right hand side of $(2)$ can vanish only if ${\bf x}'(t)$ is orthogonal to ${\bf d}$.

Similarly one argues concerning ${\partial f\over\partial s}=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Write $p_1=\gamma(t_1)$ and $p_2=\gamma(t_2)$. Consider $f(t)=<\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_1),\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_1)>$. The distance between $p_1$ and $p_2$ is maximal implies that $f'(t_2)=0$. This is equivalent to $<\gamma'(t_2),\gamma(t_2)-\gamma(t_1)>=0$. To show that $<\gamma'(t_1),\gamma(t_1)-\gamma(t_2)>=0$, use $g(t)=<\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_2),\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_2)>$.

Comment: I am confused by your use of $<$ and $>$. Also, how does this show the diameter is perpendicular to $\gamma'$ at these points...?

Comment: For me $<x,y>$ is the scalar product of $x$ and $y$, so here $f(t)=<\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_1),\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_1)>=\|\gamma(t)-\gamma(t_1)\|^2$. Which is maximal if $t=t_2$ so $f'(t_2)=0$.

Comment: @TsemoAristide: Use \langle and \rangle :)